# QGIS Heatmap Plug: Filling a radius with one color

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I'm using the heat map plug in and I want to fill in my circles with just one color that corresponds with a specific color along a gradient. My tinkering has not been fruitful and every tutorial I've found has used gradient color. Suggestions?

Comment: To clarify, you just want **every** circle to be of **one** colour?